# Compare dictionaries using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have to compare 2 dictionaries in python. For example I used the below code, it's working fine if the number of key:value pair are same in di1 and di2 but if the key:value pair is missing in di2 then code fails.

```
di1 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 9,'Alpha':'mat','Beta':'deep'};
di2 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 27,'Alpha':'rat'};
dicdiff = [k for k in di1 if di1[k] != di2[k]]
for k in dicdiff:
print k, ':', di1[k], '->', di2[k]
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't consider keys that are in `di2` but *not* in `di1` - how do you want to handle these cases? Ignore keys that aren't in both?

Comment: Yes ignore key:value pair but write them as not available in d2 which are not present in di1. Apart from this I wrote a code to find out the key:value pair which matches in di1 and di2 but not able to merge them in a single output file which says di1:di2 Name: Cat -->Matches , d1:di2 Age : 9/27--> No match

Answer (score 4):

Use [dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) and use set operations:

```
for key, value in di1.viewitems() ^ di2.viewitems():
    print '{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, value)
```

`^` gives us the symmetric difference between the two dictionaries; this will list keys present in either dictionary but missing from the other, *and* values that differ.

This produces:

```
>>> di1 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 9,'Alpha':'mat','Beta':'deep'};
>>> di2 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 27,'Alpha':'rat'};
>>> for key, value in di1.viewitems() ^ di2.viewitems():
...     print '{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, value)
... 
'Alpha': 'rat'
'Alpha': 'mat'
'Beta': 'deep'
'Age': 27
'Age': 9
```

You can refine this a little more by looking only at the keys in one or the other dictionary:

```
print 'Added keys'
for key in di2.viewkeys() - di1.viewkeys():
    print '{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, di2[key])

print 'Removed keys'
for key in di1.viewkeys() - di2.viewkeys():
    print '{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, di1[key])

print 'Changed keys'
for key in di1.viewkeys() & di2.viewkeys():
    if di1[key] != di2[key]:
        print '{!r}: {!r} -> {!r}'.format(key, di1[key], di2[key])
```

This produces:

```
>>> print 'Added keys'
Added keys
>>> for key in di2.viewkeys() - di1.viewkeys():
...     print '{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, di2[key])
... 
>>> print 'Removed keys'
Removed keys
>>> for key in di1.viewkeys() - di2.viewkeys():
...     print '{!r}: {!r}'.format(key, di1[key])
... 
'Beta': 'deep'
>>> print 'Changed keys'
Changed keys
>>> for key in di1.viewkeys() & di2.viewkeys():
...     if di1[key] != di2[key]:
...         print '{!r}: {!r} -> {!r}'.format(key, di1[key], di2[key])
... 
'Alpha': 'mat' -> 'rat'
'Age': 9 -> 27
```

Comment: Can we also used the matched keys with Added, removed and changed keys?

Comment: @robinhood: not sure what you are asking. What *matched keys* are you talking about?

Comment: @ martijn: Thanks. What I mean was the to print key:value pair which are common in both dictionary. That I have handled , its Ok. Now I am trying to compare 2 dictionaries which have different key name for example dictionary and new_dictionary has key "Name" and "my_name" so  I am creating a alias dictionary to hold "name:my_name" and then do compare but not able to achieve this by above code. For ex:
Now if name:my_name values are equal it will print match values else name:my_name are not matched

Comment: dictionary={"name":"abc","age":23,"male":True}
new_dictionary={"my_name":"abc","my_age":23,"male":1}    
dict_alias = {"name":"my_name","age":"my_age","male":"male"}
    def compare(dictionary,new_dictionary,dict_alias):
        same = True
        for key in dictionary.keys():
            if dictionary[key] == new_dictionary[dict_alias[key]]:
                continue
            else:
                same = False
                break
        return same

Answer (score 0):

You can create the set union of the keys from both dictionaries and test whether they are missing in one of the dictionaries or whether they are different.

```
for k in set(di1).union(set(di2)):
    if k not in di1:
        print k, "missing in di1"
    elif k not in di2:
        print k, "missing in di2"
    elif di1[k] != di2[k]:
        print k, ':', di1[k], '->', di2[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of all keys across both dictionaries, then use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to handle cases where the key isn't in one of the dictionaries (note that `object() != object()` - you could use `None` if that will never be an actual value):

```
def compare(d1, d2):
    """Returns a list of keys that have different values."""
    return [k for k in set(d1).union(d2)
            if d1.get(k, object()) != d2.get(k, object())]
```

In use:

```
>>> d1 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 9,'Alpha':'mat', 'Beta':'deep'}
>>> d2 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 27, 'Alpha':'rat', 'Gamma': 'foo'}
>>> for k in compare(d1, d2):
    print "{0}: {1} -> {2}".format(k, d1.get(k, "<missing>"), d2.get(k, "<missing>"))


Age: 9 -> 27
Beta: deep -> <missing>
Alpha: mat -> rat
Gamma: <missing> -> foo
```

Comment: thanks let me explored and modify code so that match case will also print

Answer (score 0):

```
di1 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 9,'Alpha':'mat','Beta':'deep'}    
di2 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 27,'Alpha':'rat', 'currency':'INR'}

# find intersection
intersection=filter(di1.has_key, di2.keys())  

keysnotindi2=list(set(di1.keys())-set(intersection))
keysnotindi1=list(set(di2.keys())-set(intersection))

# by looping on keysnotindi2 and keysnotindi1 you can get values of that particular key
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a human-readable output, rather than producing some complex data structure to feed to another bit of your code...

A lot of times you can fall back to existing diff libraries.

I do this all the time with `diff` or graphic comparison apps (Windiff, Winmerge, Kaleidoscope, etc...).

You just have to massage the data a bit in advance.  For dictionaries, use `json.dump(s)(<obj>, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`

Here's a go using `difflib` in pure Python:

```
di1 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 9,'Alpha':'mat','Beta':'deep'};
di2 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 27,'Alpha':'rat'};

import difflib
import json

differ = difflib.Differ()

text1 = json.dumps(di1, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
text2 = json.dumps(di2, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

li1 = text1.splitlines()
li2 = text2.splitlines()

diff = differ.compare(li1, li2)
for line in diff:
    print(line)
```

#### output:

```
  {
-     "Age": 9,
?            ^

+     "Age": 27,
?            ^^

-     "Alpha": "mat",
?               ^

+     "Alpha": "rat",
?               ^

-     "Beta": "deep",
      "Name": "cat"
  }
```

You could even use `assert di1 == di2` to figure out equality first and then only build the big compare stuff on an `AssertionError`.

Changing **d2** to make it a bit more complex with nesting:
 `di2 = {'Name': 'cat', 'Age': 27,'Alpha':'rat', "nested" : {"child1":"foo","child2":"bar"}};`

gives:

(truncated the bits that stayed the same)

```
-     "Beta": "deep",
-     "Name": "cat"
+     "Name": "cat",
?                  ++

+     "nested": {
+         "child1": "foo",
+         "child2": "bar"
+     }
  }
```